# Print or Save Programmatically Generated File

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I am developing an application in C# that will generate a variety of reports.  I would like to give the user the option either save the report as a PDF or print the report DIRECTLY FROM THE APPLICATION (i.e., not saving then printing).

I was under the impression that PdfSharp and MigraDocs would provide this functionality, so I have developed my report in PdfSharp. Now that I have a PDF report, but I cannot figure out how to print it without saving it first. I don't mind starting over and redeveloping my reports using a different tool, as the logic will be generally the same, but I don't want to have to develop and maintain 2 different sets of instructions depending on whether the user is saving or printing.

I have also investigated using a `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument` and MirgraDocs, but I don't think it will be dynamic enough.  I have also investigated Spire.Pdf, but the free version does not appear to be compatible with WPF.

Since this will be deployed on multiple machines, I would like to use DLLs as opposed a third party executable.

Comment: `"[...] but I cannot figure out how to print it without saving it"`. What is the problem with saving the file for printing? You can delete the file afterwards.

Comment: Looking at PdfSharp FAQ I would say it cannot print PDF's directly and so needs Adobe reader or acrobat. To do that you need to save it as a file then pass the file path to adobe reader.  Not great.